# Dynamic Number of Enum Flags Using Binary OR For FontStyles

Tags: c#, dynamic, fonts, enums

I'm in the middle of developing a feature in an application that allows a user to save their preferred font (family, size, underlined, bold, or italic).  I should start out by saying that I haven't used enums much in my first few years of developing or binary or inside a constructor for that matter so my knowledge in this area is weak.

As many know, setting up a new font is straightforward.

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
```

My question is if there is a clean way of passing into the constructor any one of the combinations of underline, bold or italic which could be none of them, maybe just bold, bold or italic, etc?

Clean to me is not having to have to do something like this.

```
if(myFont.Bold || myFont.Underline || myFont.Italic)
{
    font = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Italic);
}
else if(myFont.Bold || myFont.Underline)
{
    font = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
}
else if(myFont.Bold || myFont.Italic)
{
    font = new Font("Arial", FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
}
```

... and so forth

Comment: And what would you define as *clean*?

Comment: This isn't clear to me. What kind of code do you expect to write?

Comment: Clean to me would not be having to use logic to determine the number of font styles I need and creating 7 different constructors for the combinations of those three font styles.

Comment: Is your question is about serialization? Are you asking how to save a font and retrieve it back? I'm guessing. can't able to understand what you're asking.

Comment: No, my question is how to setup a Font object when the font could be bold or not, could be underlined or not, or could be italic or not.  I edited the original question to hopefully make things more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
string fontName = "Arial";
FontStyle style = FontStyle.Regular;

if (myFont.Bold)
    style |= FontStyle.Bold;

if (myFont.Underline)
    style |= FontStyle.Underline;

if (myFont.Italic)
    style |= FontStyle.Italic;

Font font = new Font(fontName, style);
```

Comment: FYI those logical operators ought to be |= instead of &=

Comment: @RogerN Thanks, just realized that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple constructors with the same signature, so this is a non starter, unless you artificially create dummy arguments just to differentiate them.

Instead, you should create different static methods, e.g. static MyClass CreateBoldItalic(), one for each combination you want. These will then instantiate the class with your chosen combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Use this overload of [Font's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zet4c3fa.aspx) or whichever is suitable for you.

```
Font myFont = ...;//get your font
Font font = new Font("Arial", myFont.Size, myFont.Style);
```